# Is the proposed database schema for a machine test database suitable?

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

I am creating a database to store the results of tests on machines. Is the schema I propose suitable/the best, or am I completely misunderstanding how to structure databases?

- There are different types of machines which require different tests.
- These tests use 'stock solutions', which are tested and dated to ensure they are suitable for use.
- Some machines have a syringe, which is also tested.
- All the tests are conducted in well-plates, so I need to record what the value was for a specific well in a particular plate.
- I need to record who undertook the test, so I have included a users table.

My current schema is the following:

[image: Proposed Schema]

And in XML:

(I am using the viewer here [WWW SQL Designer](https://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/).)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- SQL XML created by WWW SQL Designer, https://github.com/ondras/wwwsqldesigner/ -->
<!-- Active URL: https://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/ -->
<sql>
  <datatypes db="mysql">
    <group label="Numeric" color="rgb(238,238,170)">
      <type label="Integer" length="0" sql="INTEGER" quote="" />
      <type label="TINYINT" length="0" sql="TINYINT" quote="" />
      <type label="SMALLINT" length="0" sql="SMALLINT" quote="" />
      <type label="MEDIUMINT" length="0" sql="MEDIUMINT" quote="" />
      <type label="INT" length="0" sql="INT" quote="" />
      <type label="BIGINT" length="0" sql="BIGINT" quote="" />
      <type label="Decimal" length="1" sql="DECIMAL" re="DEC" quote="" />
      <type label="Single precision" length="0" sql="FLOAT" quote="" />
      <type label="Double precision" length="0" sql="DOUBLE" re="DOUBLE" quote="" />
    </group>
    <group label="Character" color="rgb(255,200,200)">
      <type label="Char" length="1" sql="CHAR" quote="'" />
      <type label="Varchar" length="1" sql="VARCHAR" quote="'" />
      <type label="Text" length="0" sql="MEDIUMTEXT" re="TEXT" quote="'" />
      <type label="Binary" length="1" sql="BINARY" quote="'" />
      <type label="Varbinary" length="1" sql="VARBINARY" quote="'" />
      <type label="BLOB" length="0" sql="BLOB" re="BLOB" quote="'" />
    </group>
    <group label="Date &amp; Time" color="rgb(200,255,200)">
      <type label="Date" length="0" sql="DATE" quote="'" />
      <type label="Time" length="0" sql="TIME" quote="'" />
      <type label="Datetime" length="0" sql="DATETIME" quote="'" />
      <type label="Year" length="0" sql="YEAR" quote="" />
      <type label="Timestamp" length="0" sql="TIMESTAMP" quote="'" />
    </group>
    <group label="Miscellaneous" color="rgb(200,200,255)">
      <type label="ENUM" length="1" sql="ENUM" quote="" />
      <type label="SET" length="1" sql="SET" quote="" />
      <type label="Bit" length="0" sql="bit" quote="" />
    </group>
  </datatypes>
  <table x="863" y="197" name="tests">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="test_name" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="who" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="users" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="results" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="volumetric_test_results" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="overall_pass" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="166" y="300" name="test_names">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="test_name" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="1002" y="91" name="machines">
    <row name="serial" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="part_number" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="machine_types" row="part_number" />
    </row>
    <row name="syringe" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="syringes" row="serial_number" />
    </row>
    <row name="tests_undertaken" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="tests" row="id" />
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>serial</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="1171" y="17" name="machine_types">
    <row name="part_number" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="description" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>part_number</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="600" y="302" name="volumetric_test_results">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="plate" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="plates" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="criteria" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="volumetric_test_criteria" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="pass" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="stock_solution" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="stock_solutions" row="id" />
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="363" y="294" name="volumetric_test_criteria">
    <row name="id" null="0" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="test_name" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="test_names" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="feature" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="criterion" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="volume" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="unit" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="active" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="use_wells" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="required_to_pass" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="1220" y="435" name="wells">
    <row name="plate" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="plates" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="well" null="0" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="absorbance" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>DOUBLE</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="" />
  </table>
  <table x="1217" y="285" name="plates">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="datetime" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>DATETIME</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="623" y="616" name="stock_solutions">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="plate" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="plates" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="criteria" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="stock_criteria" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="who" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="users" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="pass" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="398" y="603" name="stock_criteria">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="mean_square_error" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="slope" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="intercept" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="use_wells" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="836" y="47" name="syringes">
    <row name="serial_number" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="tests_undertaken" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="syringe_tests" row="id" />
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>serial_number</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="617" y="105" name="syringe_tests">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="criteria" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="syringe_test_criteria" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="who" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="users" row="id" />
    </row>
    <row name="pass" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="plate" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="plates" row="id" />
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="365" y="78" name="syringe_test_criteria">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="volume" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="unit" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="use_wells" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="feature" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>MEDIUMTEXT</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="711" y="771" name="users">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="first_name" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="surname" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="email" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="password_hash" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="role" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
      <relation table="roles" row="id" />
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
  <table x="858" y="823" name="roles">
    <row name="id" null="1" autoincrement="1">
      <datatype>INTEGER</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <row name="role" null="1" autoincrement="0">
      <datatype>VARCHAR</datatype>
      <default>NULL</default>
    </row>
    <key type="PRIMARY" name="">
      <part>id</part>
    </key>
  </table>
</sql>
```

Comment: Hi, what you have detailed above is a system entity relationship diagram, this details how the entities in your propsed system relate to each other.Rather than asking a farily generic question, have a read on relationships and normalisation and how this would best fit your system. After all only you will know what is the best fit when to normalise and when to not etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to review someone's design in the way you presented. However, I did notice some basic issues:

- Your `machines` table (and others) columns such as `tests_undertaken` which you indicate is of type `int`. I don't see how this makes sense. (See below).
- You have a `tests` table, but is that for the "types" of test or specific test runs on specific machines? If it's the former, then you should have a separate table that links the `tests` table to the `machines` table that contains a record for each test run on a machine and also links to the test results.
- Your `test_names` table seems unnecessary as there is no additional information provided that doesn't seem to be able to be contained in the `volumetric_test_criteria` table by simply replacing the name's `id` with the name itself. The space you save by making the extra table is probably overwhelmed by the overhead of always having to `JOIN` these two tables.

As others have pointed out, you should read up on database normalization, but I hope this helps get you started.

Comment: The `tests_undertaken` colums are `int` because they relate to specific test results, and there might be more than one… so I guess there ought to be a table between them which has the machine ID and the test ID to relate them?

The `tests` table is for specific tests on specific machines. I think this is what I have realized above. 

I have the `test_names` table because the `feature` field will be different in the same test, i.e. I want to record precision and accuracy for a particular test. I wasn't sure if this is the right way to do it though.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to store multiple specific test `id`s in a single  `tests_undertaken` column. It won't work. The solution, is to remove that column and create a `tests_undertaken` table that contains the test `id`, the machine `id` and any columns needed to store the results - such as a date/time entry, pass/fail, specific results, etc. Of course, if there are multiple "measurements" in each test result, then you might need a table for that too that provides line-by-line results for each test "run". Determining these things is the "art" of database design.